# wp_enqueue_media is not loading styles

Tags: css, media-library

I'm trying to upload images from the frontend using Wordpress default media uploader, so I used wp_enqueue_media(). It imports all the scripts but not the styles.
See the screenshot below
[image: wordpress media uploader]

After using the inspect tool I found out that it was not loading the load-styles.php from wp-includes. How do I fix this?

Comment: The styles are imported, but your theme's styles are overwriting some of them. You'll need to manually fix any issues with your own CSS.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, so I created a theme file with no css of my own (or any frameworks) and just used the media uploader. But it still has the same issues. Not loading styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some wp-admin styles you need to load.

Since I cannot find any way to let wp_enqueue_style() accept url parameters, so I load styles by wp_head hook function here.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'load_admin_media_styles', 10);
function load_admin_media_styles(){
    // list all style libs the post page of wp-admin loaded, but we may only need to load 2 of them
    $ary_libs = array(
        'common','forms',
        // 'dashicons', 'admin-bar','buttons','media-views',
        // 'admin-menu','dashboard','list-tables','edit','revisions','media','themes','about','nav-menu',
        // 's','wp-pointer','widgets','site-icon','l10n','wp-auth-check','wp-color-picker'
    );
    $admin_media_styles_url = add_query_arg(
        array(
            'c' => 0,
            'dir' => 'ltr',
            'load[]' => implode(',', $ary_libs),
            'ver' => 'you_wp_version'
        ),
        admin_url().'load-styles.php'
    );
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin_styles_for_media-css' href='".$admin_media_styles_url."' type='text/css' media='all' />";
}
```

I tried in my localhost and it works, hope this helps you.

Comment: **get_bloginfo('version')** will give you the current version of wordpress your site is running. You can use that where @Audi Lu has _'you_wp_version'_